# Why does this line numbering command mangle the character encoding?

Tags: linux, perl, encoding

I'd like to modify a file by adding line numbers to the beginning of each line. I've found that the following command does this:

`cat file | perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' > file_with_line_numbers`

This seems to work, however, when I open the file in vim it's full of ^@ and ^M characters. Further investigation shows that the encoding has changed.

```
> file -bi file
text/plain; charset=utf-16le

> file -bi file_with_line_numbers
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You could just use nl. This is what it was made for. `nl file > new_file_with_line_numbers`

Comment: @squiguy, Nope, `nl` will fail in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decode your program's input and encode your program's output.

As ysth points out, this will do the trick (except on Windows, but probably using cygwin):

```
perl -Mopen=:std,':encoding(utf-16le)' -pe'$_="$. $_";' file.in >file.out
```

---

Rest of original answer:

This is easiest done if you have UTF-8, since you can then use `-CSDA`.

```
<file.in iconv -f UTF-16le -t UTF-8 \
   | perl -CSDA -pe'$_="$. $_";' \
     | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16le \
       >file.out
```

Due to properties of UTF-8, you can get away without decoding/encoding completely in this case, allowing you to use either of the following:

```
<file.in iconv -f UTF-16le -t UTF-8 \
   | perl -pe'$_="$. $_";' \
     | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16le \
       >file.out
```

or

```
<file.in iconv -f UTF-16le -t UTF-8 \
   | nl \
     | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16le \
       >file.out
```

Comment: haven't tried it, but wouldn't `perl -Mopen=:std,:encoding'(utf-16le)' ...` work?

Comment: you mean if you provide the input file in @ARGV?

Comment: huh; I thought that open.pm encoding didn't apply to ARGV at some point but was later fixed, but I just tried on 5.8.8 and 5.14.2 and both seemed to work

Comment: Ah cool! just verified. That's good. Won't work on Windows because of the bad ordering of :crlf, but the OP appears to use unix (cygwin?). Updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

Because you're not decoding your input data and you're not encoding your output data, and by concatenating `$.` with `$_` you're mixing data that are in two different encodings (rather, you're mixing a byte-string and a character string, but perl is implicitly converting the byte string to a character string, and doing it in a very wrong way for what you need).

One fix would be:

```
perl -pe  'BEGIN { binmode STDIN, ":encoding(utf16le)"; binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf16le)" } $_ = "$. $_";' < input > output
```

Comment: The explanation got me started, but I wound up with code almost identical to that of the answer submitted by @ikegami.